# Increased rmem_default, wmem_default, but still errno 90 (Message too long)

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp, udp

I am trying to write to a socket, something of which is of size bigger than the default wmem_default. So I did the following to increase the write and read buffer size.

```
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_default=500000
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=1000000
sysctl -w net.core.wmem_default=5000000
sysctl -w net.core.wmem_max=1000000
```

Even after increasing these, the system still spits out errno 90  (Message too long). What's the next possible cause for such an error? I am using udp socket here, with setsockopt(...,SO_SNDBUF,...)

Comment: The length field in a UDP datagram is two bytes, limiting the size of a UDP datagram to about 65000 bytes (with some additional possibilities to exceed this limit in IPv6 only); and the maximum size is also limited by the underlying transport's limitation. BTW -- all this information was located by a Google search that only took a few seconds. You should try that approach, sometimes...

Comment: Um, would any IP stack even try to assemble a packet fragmented into 50 pieces? Seems like nothing but a DoS vector.